# Returning multiple model details to a Laravel resource

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Im trying to return results for 2 models into one resource and finding it a bit difficult to understand.

I have a 'project', this project can have multiple 'members' and it can also have people that have been 'invited' ... I want to return a list of all members associated with the project and also all people that currently have pending invites in the invite table.

My 'project' table has the following relationship

```php
public function members(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Member::class);
}
```

and it also has another relationship;

```php
public function invites(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Invite::class);
}
```

In my controller i have

```php
$data = [
    'members' => $project->members()->get(),
    'invites' => $project->invites()->get()
];
```

But i am having trouble figuring out how to return this in a resource .. Or even if this is the best way to return the data, is there a better way using Eloquent?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the $project model name, is it `Project`?

Answer (score 1):

using a resource:

```php
/**
 * @property Project $resource
 */
class ProjectResource extends Resource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            // other project fields
            'members' => MemberApiResource::collection($this->resource->members),
            'invites' => InviteApiResource::collection($this->resource->invites),
        ];
    }
}
```

than in your controller:

```php
public function show(Project $project): JsonResponse
{
    $project->load(['members', 'invites']);

    return (new ProjectResource($project))->toResponse($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you load the relationships then you shouldn't really have to do much.

Assuming you have a route like this:

```php
Route::get('/projects/{project}', [ProjectController::class, 'show'])->name('projects.show');
```

Your controller can simply return the model with its relationships.

```php
public function show(Project $project)
{
    $project->load(['members', 'invites']);

    return $project;
}
```

or if you're returning data do a view

```php
return view('projects.show', ['project' => $project]);
```

```xml
{{ $project->id }}
{{ $project->... }}
@foreach ($project->members as $member)
  {{ $member->id }}
  {{ $member->... }}
@endforeach
@foreach ($project->invites as $invite)
  {{ $invite->id }}
  {{ $invite->... }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I was wondering what a Resource class would look like with multiple tables ... Is there any chance you would know?

Comment: Assume that Resource class is a simple formatter, there you can customise the data passing from the model, the data you are formatting in Resource class can be the fields from model, are an another resource or an another collection. It will go on

Watch this video this might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAscQPIm_jY

Answer (score 0):

```
return \App\Models\Project->with([
    'members', 
    'invites'
])->get();
```